# Error reading Atom feeds

Tags: vb.net, xml-parsing, rss, atom-feed

The code below is failing when I'm trying to read atom feeds from a specific website. The error im getting is: **'Text' is an invalid XmlNodeType** .
I have pasted the feed to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/3VBPDvGX) and unfortunately I cannot provide direct link to the feed since it includes private access information.

My Code:

```
Using reader = XmlReader.Create(FeedURL)
    Dim atomContent = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader)
    Dim rvArr = atomContent.Items.Reverse()
    For Each entry As Object In rvArr
        Dim title As String = entry.title.text
        Dim excerpt As String = "excerpt" '
        Dim content As String = entry.summary.text
        Dim ndate As String = Convert.ToDateTime(entry.LastUpdatedTime.ToString()).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm")
    Next
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

In this feed there is at line 4 a link to the feed, what is in my case 'access denied'/protected.
If I remove this line 4 from the feed, the code runs without the error showing up.

Comment: Is there anyway to remove or skip the link?